# log4net %thread pattern evaluated to TimeoutExecutor

Tags: log4net

I configured log4net with the following pattern.

```
<conversionPattern value="%date %-5level (%thread) %logger - %message%newline" />
```

I expected a threadId in the resulting log, but sometimes I also get a string, like

2016-11-25 10:39:28,405 WARN  **(TimeoutExecutor 4)**

What is that "TimeoutExecutor" string that I see?

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html), the `%thread` placeholder is:

> Used to output the name of the thread that generated the logging event. Uses the thread number if no name is available.

So something in your application has given that thread a name, which is what you see in the logs.